# Bringing up EC2 instances with vagrant-aws errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ruby, automation, vagrant

I'm trying to automate acceptance testing by using vagrant to bring up machines with amazon's EC2 service, so I added the dummy box and copied the Vagrantfile off [Github](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws), but when I try to run `vagrant up --provider=aws` I get the output below:
I'm fairly new to ruby and so I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong.

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...

> [default] Warning! The AWS provider doesn't support any of the
>   Vagrant
>  high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`).
>   They
>  will be silently ignored.
>  [default] Launching an
>   instance with the following settings...
>  [default]  -- Type:
>   m1.small
>  [default]  -- AMI: ami-5344d263
>  [default]  --
>   Region: us-east-1
>  [default]  -- Keypair: vagrant-keypair
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in
>   `response_call': Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)
>   (Excon::Errors::BadRequest)   from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:353:in`
>   response'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/excon-0.25.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in
>   `request'     from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:21:in`
>   request'     from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:384:in
>   `_request'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:379:in`
>   request'     from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/run_instances.rb:119:in
>   `run_instances'   from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/aws/models/compute/server.rb:173:in`
>   save'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.10.1/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:52:in
>   `create'  from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.2.2/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:76:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.2.2/lib/vagrant-aws/action/warn_networks.rb:14:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.2.2/lib/vagrant-aws/action/sync_folders.rb:21:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:45:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in`
>   block in run'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in
>   `busy'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in`
>   run'     from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'    from
>   /home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.2.2/lib/vagrant-aws/action/connect_aws.rb:41:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in
>   `call'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in`
>   block in run'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in
>   `busy'    from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in`
>   run'     from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in
>   `action'  from
>   /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in`
>   block (2 levels) in run'

Error when running after recompiling:

An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
Any errors that occurred are shown below.

```
An unexpected error ocurred when executing the action on the
'default' machine. Please report this as a bug:

undefined method `Errors' for Excon:Module

/home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.3.0.dev/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:91:in `rescue in call'
/home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.3.0.dev/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:61:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.3.0.dev/lib/vagrant-aws/action/warn_networks.rb:14:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.3.0.dev/lib/vagrant-aws/action/sync_folders.rb:21:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:45:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.3.0.dev/lib/vagrant-aws/action/connect_aws.rb:41:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box_url.rb:72:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from this patch which should log the actual bad response: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/101

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Tried using this patch and compiled it from source, still getting the same error.

Comment: Scratch that, compiled it again and outputs a different (no less cryptic) error

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to incorrect ami for the region<sup>[#101](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/101#issuecomment-19828865)</sup>.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/commit/5853ebecc0d6d962b556e4da591c0fafb59da908) in the recent [`vagrant-aws`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws), so please upgrade your [gems](https://rubygems.org/gems/vagrant-aws) via:

```
vagrant plugin update
```

or apply the patch from the [pull request](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/101) by the following steps:

```
cd ~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-*/
patch -p1 <(curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/101.patch)
```